# Python fiona errors when using geopandas

Tags: python, conda, geopandas, fiona

I have tried multiple ways of creating new conda environments to allow the use of geopandas, but everything I try in every environment I've created, I run into the same error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.27.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fiona/ogrext.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Has anyone found a way that works? I've tried conda-forge installing fiona, creating empty conda env and pip installing what I need, but all give the same error.

I've created bare conda envs to test with like so

```
conda create --name conda_env
```

And then pip install as I need.

Comment: Show us the ways you've tried to create a new environment. Without seeing that, all we can say is, "keep trying"

Comment: That error implies that the `site-packages` of a user-level install of Python 3.9 is on `sys.path`. Conda does not have well-defined behavior when other Python installs leak into the environment. First, ensure you are activating the correct environment. Then, make sure no shell variables like "PYTHONPATH" are set.

Comment: use conda to install geopandas from the conda-forge channel (`conda create --name=gis python=3.8 geopandas --channel=conda-forge`)